# Resources for storing and quickly referencing your commonly used code?

Tags: version-control

As a programmer I feel we are constantly reusing old code... after all the trick is to learn how to do it the first time, store it, and then reuse and build off of it for the future.

Right now I have a Trello board that is designated to code reference. I have many different decks labeled with a specific code (CSS, HTML, Angular, etc...) and inside are cards with the common code that I often use or reference for if I forget how in the future. You can see it here (http://prntscr.com/ccrrgv).

This is great but as my Trello decks expand to 20, 40, and 60 cards it becomes tricky to find the card. I feel this must be a common problem for programmers and I am curious of how they are referencing their code or if an application exists that is built for referencing and quickly accessing your old code.

I am curious of your organization techniques. Thanks everyone!

Comment: sign up for github

https://github.com/